# Error in Datadrift Monitor in Azure ML - Analyze existing data

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I have created a monitor using Data drift detector in Azure ML.

When I am monitoring it through studio interface using data---->data monitor
it shows below error.

"Failed to load metrics.
Service is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later"

I am unable to see metrics visualization for analyzing data drift.

Even in notebook also it goes in Queue state for long time and don't display metric.

[Data Drift Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk5Ns.png)

Comment: The image is not clear which was shared. Change the image and make a clear explanation of the error.

Comment: Please see attached sample notebook  link from github related to Datadrift on diabetis dataset.            https://github.com/MicrosoftLearning/mslearn-dp100/blob/main/17%20-%20Monitor%20Data%20Drift.ipynb

When I am trying to execute it, the monitor gets created using the datadriftdetector class, but when the backfill method is called, it takes too much time to execute.
The job remains in running. Even after 2-3 hrs, it still cannot fetch metrics. I want understand metrics in data drift in azure.  please help.